# Where are scenes set in newspaper printing press rooms filmed?

Tags: production

For newspaper films, it seems de rigeur to have a scene shot in the printing press room. "The Post" (2017) is a recent example, with extensive printing scenes including close-ups of typesetting and shots of newspapers flying along the delivery belt (though doesn't show the printing drums or folding).

Where are these sort of shots made? It would seem too expensive for a studio to maintain a printing room. Is there a museum that maintains running presses? Are there still commercial printers that use the old typesetters that then show up in film?

Comment: You are asking too many questions all at once. Try narrowing the question to just one..

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/toronto/printing-presses-for-washington-posts-pentagon-papers-coverage-live-on-in-ontario/article38140176/):

> **The New York Post's printing presses were used to film the pivotal scenes in *The Post***, and Ms. Streep said it was "thrilling" to see them at work.
>
> "It was like stepping back in time," the actor says in the film's production notes. "It gave me the chills."

[Additionally](https://museumofprinting.org/news-and-events/mop-in-movies/):

> Some of the equipment used to recreate the hot-metal composition of the time, came from the Museum of Printing — not to mention the Linotype operator and the Bodoni display fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are "Print/Printing" museums that keep such machines. In most of them (or in all I visited) the machines are in working conditions and serve as a show and tell or just wait to be used in workshops.

Also there is a quite large market for old type printing. Although now it's mainly for small batches (invitiations, brochures, high quality flyers).

In the linked scene the first machine Linotype is real and this is how it worked. Then the paper on the rolls are CGI. The final product that goes on racks through drying part are premade sets. Probably printed on modern machine with better quality paper to look good on film.